# Hartree-Fock: Coulomb integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations

Today I was wondering how to better understand the [Coulomb integral](http://www.google.com/search?q=coulomb+integral) in the [Hartree-Fock approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method).

Extracted from: [Szabo & Ostlund, Modern Quantum Chemistry](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486691861.html), p. 112

> The Coulomb term has a simple interpretation. In an exact
>   theory, the Coulomb interaction is represented by the two-electron
>   operator $r_{ij}^{-1}$. In the Hartree-Fock approximation, an electron in
>   a state $\chi_{a}$ experiences a one-electron Coulomb potential:
>
> $$
>     v_{a}^\text{coul}(1) = \sum_{b \neq a} \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} | \chi_{b}(2) |^{2} r_{12}^{-1} \tag{3.7}
> $$

Now, the Coulomb integral (*CI*) for a system of two interacting electrons, using [Slater determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant), is:

$$\hat{J}=\frac{1}{2} \left( \int \psi_1^*\left( 1 \right) \psi_2^*\left( 2 \right) \frac{1}{r_{12}} \psi_2\left( 1 \right)\psi_1\left( 2 \right) + \psi_2^*\left( 1 \right) \psi_1^*\left( 2 \right) \frac{1}{r_{12}} \psi_1\left( 1 \right)\psi_2\left( 2 \right) \mathrm{d}x \right)$$

Now, the help I'm looking for how this single Slater determinant definition comes up from the mathematical point of view.

This is how I understand the HF approximation: Let's start only with the *Coulomb integral*. This integral, as I understand it, should be understood as follows for the first electron:

\begin{align}\text{CI} & =\int \psi_1^*\left( 1 \right) \psi_2^*\left( 2 \right) \frac{1}{r_{12}} \psi_2\left( 1 \right)\psi_1\left( 2 \right) \mathrm{d}x \\
& =\int \psi_1^*\left( 1 \right) \big( \sum_{n=2}^{n=2} \psi_2^*\left( 2 \right) \frac{1}{r_{12}} \psi_1\left( 2 \right) \big) \psi_2\left( 1 \right) \mathrm{d}x\\
& =\int \psi_1^*\left( 1 \right) \big( \sum_{n=2}^{n=2} \hat{J}_n \big) \psi_2\left( 1 \right)\end{align}

And, more general, the Coulomb integral for the first electron in a system of $n$ electrons would be:

$$\text{CI}= \int \psi_1^*\left( 1 \right) \big( \sum_{n \neq 1}^{n} \hat{J}_n \big) \psi_2\left( 1 \right) \mathrm{d}x$$

Is this correct?

If this is not correct, would someone enlighten me?

To *ACuriousMind*, Thank so much for editing this post.

**Specific help I'm looking for:**

I'll try to explain myself better through these questions:

i.) This operator $\frac{1}{r_{ij}}$ involves the spatial coordinates of electrons $i$ and $j$. So, taken this *CI*:

$$J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1) := \Big[ \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2) \Big] \chi_{1}(1)$$

*Mathematically speaking*, the first step is to integrate $\int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2)$ (which only the spatial coordinates of electron 2 are taken in account) and then multiply the result to $\chi_1 \left( 1 \right)$ ?

ii.) This question is more curiosity. For the same electron (Let's say the first one), How would it be with a system of N-electrons?

Comment: This question seems too confused and poorly edited to even begin to give an answer. I would recommend you check out the book by Bethe "Intermediate Quantum Mechanics", he goes over this in great detail.

Comment: I have already read from page 58 to 64. But in the book you suggested me still is not answering my question. The only difference is that explicitly include the spin.

Comment: @Alejandro looks like you are badly and totally confused by the HF method. Basically, all you statements and formulas are "not quite right" to put it mildly. Szabo & Ostlund book is quite good at explaining the HF method, but you have to be careful and patient to follow through.

Comment: Hi Alejandro! I have edited your question for better formatting and grammar, and I don't think I've changed the meaning of anything, but I still cannot discern what your actual *question* really is except that you do not really understand the HF approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the Coulomb integral for a system of two interacting electrons,
>   until Slater determinants, is:

I don't understand what the heck do you mean by "until Slater determinants", but for a system of two electrons you have a system of two HF equations (3.9): each HF equation for each spin-orbital $\chi_{a}$,
$$
    [h(1) + J_{2}(1) - K_{2}(1) ] \, \chi_{1}(1) = \varepsilon_{1} \chi_{1}(1) \, , \\
    [h(1) + J_{1}(1) - K_{1}(1) ] \, \chi_{2}(1) = \varepsilon_{2} \chi_{2}(1) \, , \\
$$
where 
$$
    J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1) := \Big[ \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2) \Big] \chi_{1}(1) \, , \\
    K_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1) := \Big[ \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{1}(2) \Big] \chi_{2}(1) \, , \\
    J_{1}(1) \chi_{2}(1) := \Big[ \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{1}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{1}(2) \Big] \chi_{2}(1) \, , \\
    K_{1}(1) \chi_{2}(1) := \Big[ \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{1}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2) \Big] \chi_{1}(1) \, . \\
$$

So, you have two different Coulomb terms $J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1)$ and $J_{1}(1) \chi_{2}(1)$, as well as two different exchange terms $K_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1)$ and $K_{1}(1) \chi_{2}(1)$, entering each and every HF equation.

*Coulomb integrals* are expression of the following form 
$$
    \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \chi_{1}^{*}(1) J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1) \, , \\
    \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \chi_{2}^{*}(1) J_{1}(1) \chi_{2}(1) \, ,
$$
which contribute to the HF electronic energy $\langle \Phi\,|\,H\,|\,\Phi\rangle$.
By the definition of Coulomb operator $J_{2}(1)$ above could be written as follows
$$
    \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \chi_{1}^{*}(1) \Big[ \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2) \Big] \chi_{1}(1) \, , \\
    \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \chi_{2}^{*}(1) \Big[ \int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{1}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{1}(2) \Big] \chi_{2}(1) \, ,
$$
or as follows
$$
    \iint \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \chi_{1}^{*}(1) \chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2) \chi_{1}(1) \, , \\
    \iint \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \chi_{2}^{*}(1) \chi_{1}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{1}(2) \chi_{2}(1) \, .
$$

Comment: nope, until this point, I guess, I understand it pretty well. I'll try to explain myself better through these questions: i.) This operator $\frac{1}{r_{ij}}$ involves the spatial coordinates of electrons $i$ and $j$. So, taken the first Coulomb expression of your last list. Mathematically speaking, first this integral $\int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{2} \, \chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2)$ (which only the spatial coordinates of electron 2 are into the integral) must be integrated and then multiplied to $\chi_{1}(1)$ ? and ii.) (with N-e) it would the same with the N-1 remaining electrons?

Comment: @Alejandro I just wrote expression for Coulomb integrals explicitly. So, for instance, for the first Coulomb integral, you can think of it as follows. You first calculate the average Coulomb potential $J_{2}(1)$ which e-1 "feels" due to e-2 on $\chi_{2}$ by integrating $\chi_{2}^{*}(2) r_{12}^{-1} \chi_{2}(2)$ over coordinates of e-2. You then calculate the resulting Coulomb repulsion energy between e-1 on $\chi_{1}$ and e-2 on $\chi_{2}$ by integrating $\chi_{1}(1) J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1)$ over coordinates of e-1.

Comment: @Alejandro, and yes, for an $N$-electron system you indeed do calculate all such Coulomb contributions for e-1 with all other $N-1$ electrons in the system. And you do the same of e-2, and e-3, etc. You then sum up all the Coulomb integrals (minus all the exchange ones) together with the sum of all core Hamiltonian energies to calculate the HF energy.

Comment: Thanks Wildcat and you just highlight the part that I'm not clearly understand. I clearly understand until the first integral (integrating $\chi_{2}^{*} \left( 2 \right) \frac{1}{r_{12}} \chi_{2} \left( 2 \right)$ ). The second part is not clear to me: the result of the first integral, I mess up with these options: a.) I include it into the definition of the second integral or b.) integrate the second integral with the coloumb operator and then multiply it for the result of the first integral? Thank so much in advance : )

Comment: @Alejandro, now it looks like you are missing the second integration which enters an expression for a Coulomb integral. So $J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1)$ is *not* a Coulomb integral, it just an expression which defines the Coulomb operator $J_{2}(1)$ by its action on spin-orbital $\chi_{1}(1)$. The corresponding Coulomb integral is written as follows $\int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \chi_{1}(1) J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1)$.

Comment: @Alejandro, as I said, you can first calculate $J_{2}(1)$ using its definition and integrating over coordinates of e-2. You than can substitute the resulting potential $J_{2}(1)$ into $\int \mathrm{d} \vec{x}_{1} \chi_{1}^{*}(1) J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1)$ and integrate over coordinates of e-1. So, you multiply $J_{2}(1)$ by $\chi_{1}(1)$ from the right and by its complex-conjugate $\chi_{1}^{*}(1)$ from the lefts and then integrate.

Comment: @Alejandro, oh, I think I got it. You have a problem with understanding this rather awkward physicists' notation for integrals which Szabo & Ostlund (and I following them) use in the book in which differentials come first. :D In this notation *everything* after differentials is integrand expression. So, yeah, you integrate the whole $\chi_{1}^{*}(1) J_{2}(1) \chi_{1}(1)$.

Comment: @Alejandro, also note that I forgot to complex conjugate $\chi_{1}(1)$ to the left of $J_{2}(1)$ in few of my comments above and I couldn't edit them already.

Comment: Yes fourth backward and I was getting until third backward. With two backward I got lost again, with the differential notation is ok. In summary: First integrate: $\int dx_2 x_2^{*}(2) \frac{1}{r_{12}} x_2(2)$ and integrate over spatial coordinates of electron 2. Then, this result I multiply to the right with $X_1(1)$ _and_ (This partial result) multiply to the left with $X_1^*(1)$ and integrate over spacial coordinates of electron 1. Do you think that I finally and almost tightly get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22097/discussion-between-wildcat-and-alejandro).